# Primary Current in a Transformer

Tags: current, transformer

[image]

In the image attached above, the book uses I2 = V2/Z2. However, the question says "primary is excited by 200V". So, V2 should be 100V. Is the solution wrong then.

Question for reference: [Question](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=dh_gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=A%20transformer%20has%20150%20primary%20turns%20and%2075%20secondary%20turns.%20Its%20%20primary%20is%20excited%20at%20200%20V%20and%20the%20secondary%20is%20loaded%20with%20an%20impedance%20of%205%3C30%C2%B0%20%20Calculate%20the%20primary%20current%20and%20its%20pf.%20State%20assumptions%20made&source=bl&ots=uJOYaUSnFM&sig=ACfU3U0HLalSbkA4EmDsJhdUfphA3Nb1Yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR3724vbLwAhXowzgGHSRXA6gQ6AEwCXoECAYQAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)
Book : Basic Electrical Engineering, McGrawhill

Comment: It also looks like they got the ratio wrong in the calculation of `I1` (`75/100`, instead of `75/150`).

Comment: Check math.  It may be with 150.  Typos show up all the time in textbooks.